# Custom Font Showing Custom(none installed) in WatchKit InterfaceFile

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I want to select "Custom" option from Attribute Inspector of WatchKit Interface for UILabel but its disabled.
Is Any one facing the same problem? Please give me direction if I am missing any thing;
[image]

I am using XCode Version 6.2 (6C131e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard iOS fonts are only standard on iOS devices. They are not included on Apple Watch.

The documentation shows this list of all standard WatchKit font styles:

[image]

Note the phrase "none installed" in your screenshot.

If you want to use **any other font**, you'll need to install a custom font. From [the WatchKit docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html):

> To use custom fonts, you must install those fonts by doing the following:
>
> - Include the custom font file in both your WatchKit app and your WatchKit extension bundle.
> - Add the `UIAppFonts` key to your WatchKit app’s Info.plist file, and use it to specify the fonts you added to the bundle. For more information about this key, see Information Property List Key Reference.

Comment: I want to look Standard Fonts List that we can able to see in regular Interface file of iPhone/iPad xib. List will be open once that option will be enabled.

Comment: Those fonts are only standard on iOS devices. They are not included on Apple Watch.